# Conflicto en programa windows form con arreglos en C# (Datos calculados no se presentan)

Tags: c#, windows-forms, matemáticas, array

Estoy realizando una practica para un caso de fisica en que involucra donde un objeto en reposo se mueve en un plano inclinado donde al final de la pendiente el objeto cae libremente, el objeto al caer agarra aun velocidad y recorre una distancia, se pide calcular la distancia despues de la caida.

Es en mi caso de que los valores al terminar de calcular varios valores no me leen, me dicen: "NaN" o "0".

[image: Programa visual para practica de fisica]

Como se puede ver la aceleracion, el tiempo de caida, la distancia recorrida y las velocidades (Tanto en horizontal, como en caida y por la pendiente) no son dadas para salir.

El codigo estructurado es el siguiente:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double[] ang, Xp, H, Tiempo, Acel, Vx, Vy, X, Vf, coef, rad;
        double d1, d2, g = 9.81, g2 = 4.9, d3;
        ang = new double[5]; Tiempo = new double[5]; Acel = new double[5]; H = new double[5];
        Xp = new double[5]; Vx = new double[5]; Vy = new double[5]; Vf = new double[5]; X = new double[5];
        coef = new double[5]; rad = new double[5];
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            ang[i] = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
            Xp[i] = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
            H[i] = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
            rad[i] = ((ang[i] * Math.PI) / 180);
            coef[i] = Math.Round(Math.Tan(rad[i]),3); //Los valores del coeficiente si se muestran.
            Acel[i] = Math.Round((g * (Math.Sin(rad[i]) - (coef[i] * Math.Cos(rad[i])))), 2);
            Vf[i] = Math.Round(Math.Sqrt(2 * Acel[i] * Xp[i]), 2);
            Vx[i] = Math.Round(Vf[i] * Math.Cos(rad[i]), 2);
            Vy[i] = Math.Round(Vf[i] * Math.Sin(rad[i]), 2);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) // Aqui se realiza el despeje de la formula de fisica para el tiempo a formula general.
        {
            d3 = 2 * g2;
            d2 = (-4 * g2 * Xp[i]);
            d1 = Math.Round(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Vy[i], 2) + d2), 2);
            Tiempo[i] = ((-Vy[i]) + d1) / d3;
            X[i] = Vx[i] * Tiempo[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            dataGridView8.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = Convert.ToString(Vf[i]);
            dataGridView8.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = Convert.ToString(Vx[i]);
            dataGridView8.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = Convert.ToString(Vy[i]);
            dataGridView4.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = Convert.ToString(Acel[i]);
            dataGridView5.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = Convert.ToString(Tiempo[i]);
            dataGridView6.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = Convert.ToString(X[i]);
        }
    }
```

Los valores del coeficiente los consulte en el depurador y si me dan de que es 0.7, siendo que el tangente del radian del angulo de 35 grados es 0.7 
No se exactamente cual es el error de que los valores no se presenten o si la formula para calcular no esta correcta.

Este error no se porque se me presenta en este caso, siendo que en otras practicas para windows form con manejo de arreglos por GridView si se me visualizan los datos.

Agradeceria que este asunto este resuelto lo mas pronto posible.

Comment: Agrega un breakpoint en cualquiera de las instrucciones donde tomas un dato de algun GridView; creo el ".Cells[0]" (en el primer for) estas comando la primer columna que no tiene dato; prueba con ".Cells[1]".

Comment: el caso en Cells[0] es para la primera columna, no se puede con Cells[1] porque el GridView nomas tiene 1 columna

Comment: Una cosa es que el valor del coeficiente si me da que es 0.7, debido a que tangente del radian de 35 es 0.7. El problema es que con los otros valores no se me presentan.

Comment: Ya he intentado como cambiar la secuencia de for o agregar mas secuencias, pero aun asi me no se me presentan los datos.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema creo que tiene que ver con el redondeo que haces al calcular la aceleración:

```
Acel[i] = Math.Round((g * (Math.Sin(rad[i]) - (coef[i] * Math.Cos(rad[i])))), 2);
```

El problema es que lo significativo de la aceleración está a partir del tercer decimal. Si modificas esa linea por:

```
Acel[i] = g * (Math.Sin(rad[i]) - (coef[i] * Math.Cos(rad[i])));
```

Creo que los resultados `Vf,Vx y Vy` serán los esperados.

Por otro lado, no le veo el sentido a repetir la misma operación 5 veces con los mismos datos de entrada.